# how to remove the bracket around a list that contains list

Tags: python, numpy

for exemple if I write:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[1,2]]
output: 
[[1,2,3],[1,2]]
```

but if I write:

```
a = [1,2,3],[1,2]
output:
([1,2,3],[1,2])
```

I need to get from

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2]]
to
([1,2,3],[1,2])
```

because I append some stuff in a list and after that I want to convert the list into a numpy array, which needs to be in this notation:

```
([1,2,3],[1,2])
```

how do I do that?

Comment: note that python tuples are immutable, and you cannot append values to a python tuple. It's better to stick to a list and call `np.ndarray(a)`

Comment: Why do you need a tuple (of lists) to create a `numpy` array?  I can't think of an array input that needs that.  Structured arrays need a list of tuples. OK, a more complex dtype could have lists within those tuples.

Comment: Maybe you can make your question more clear, and I agree with @hpaulj's idea that you don't need a tuple to create a numpy array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[1,2]]

tuple(a)
```

Result:

```
([1,2,3],[1,2])
```